# Generated random value (uuid) in Pentaho as Column value?

Tags: postgresql, etl, uuid, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a transformation in Pentaho which looks like this:

[image]

This transformation populates a table `PRO_T_TICKETS` in PostgreSQL.
And this table primary key is named `OID` and has the `uuid` data type.

Here is a snip of my Database Join query:

[image]

I want to use the generated random value by Pentaho as column value for `OID`.

My question is where should I place the step "Generate random value (OID)" in my Pentaho job flow and what editing should I make in my db join so the join selects this generated `uuid` as its value?

Comment: There is no join on OID, just a select !

Comment: Yes. I was referring to the Pentaho step, not the OID individually.

Comment: Your transformation cannot work because the sort row has no input. More important, it cannot work because the joins (the two of them) , only have one input flow. A join needs two input to join them. Please provide understandable example.

Comment: That is done by Mistake. All the steps are connected.

Comment: I did not get you on the input flow part?  What two inputs you are talking about?

Comment: Ah, OK, my mistake, I was confusing with the Join Rows step.

Comment: What about removing the uuid() as OID from the SQL and name OID the random generated value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data flow as you want except it has no OID. Make the flow to cross the `Generate random value` and name it OID. That should be the flow you are looking for.

Also, be kind for us, clean you example and remove all what is not mandatory to understand the problem (like sort, normalizer and the kind of sort).

Comment: Now I am passing OID as a parameter in my SQL query. OID gets generated and table PRO_T_TICKETS has OID as its primary key. I can't generate Unique OIDs using this. OID is the primary key of my table.
@AlainD

Comment: I do not follow. Is the OID generated by the `SQL Join` or by the `Generate Random` ? If you right click on the `Daten SAP_Bcone` and `Show input fields`, do you see  column named `OID` ? And if you do the same on `Generate random value (OID)`, do you see an additional  column named `OID_1` ?

Comment: Hey. Got it solved. I was passing OID as a parameter in my join query. Instead, I should have used "Generate Random Value (OID)" step just before the table_output step. And after that just map the OID field with the target column name. 

Thanks for all the help ! :) @AlainD

Comment: Nice for you. Make a picture of the working transformation, and answer to yourself. For the next ones...

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use any data to generate uuid then u can just do something

```
create sequence uuid_sequence_sample;
create table atest(oid uuid default uuid_generate_v5(uuid_ns_url(), cast(nextval('uuid_sequence_sample') as text)), id int, name text);

insert into atest(id, name) values(12, 'hello');

select * from atest;

oid                                  | id | name
-------------------------------------------------
b80c8fef-a677-5340-85fb-2c162d75df03 | 12 | hello
```